# Apply image filter to Fabric.js text object

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Is there any way to apply image filter to text object in fabric.js? I'm using image filter to hide boundary content and I need to apply this to text object as well. But image object doesn't have option to apply filters.

```
var textn = new fabric.Text('Hello world', {
  fill: 'black',
  left: canvas.width / 2,
  top: canvas.height / 2
})
canvas.add(textn);
textn.cloneAsImage(function (pgClone) {
  pgClone.set({ 
    left: canvas.width / 2, 
    top: canvas.height / 2, 
    djtext: $('#addText').val() 
  });
  canvas.add(pgClone);
  canvas.setActiveObject(pgClone);
  canvas.renderAll();
});
canvas.remove(textn);
canvas.renderAll();
```

I tried `cloneAsImage` method. It works, but whenever I want to modify text object I need to recreate text elements again.